# PHP cant write files regardless of permissions

Tags: centos, php, permissions, apache-2.4, centos7

On a Centos 7x64 box apache/php is unable to write files regardless of permissions. I set the directory to apache:apache and even set it to 777 and php is still getting permission errors.

What else could possibly be denying PHP from writing files?

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: yes it looks like it is

Comment: I set it to permissive and it is working now. Ill read up on selinux so I can set the correct permissions and set it back to enforced or should I just leave it at permissive?

Answer (score 2):

You can set SELinux to permissive mode in order to analyze.

```
    # setenforce 0
```

SELinux will log but permit to access. So you can check the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for details. Maybe you will need to change SELinux context. For this, you will use `chcon` command. If you need, show us your `audit.log` for more detailed answer.

Don't forget to enable SELinux after you solve the problem. It's better keep SELinux enforced.

```
    # setenforce 1
```